# Mysqldump error

Tags: php, mysql

```
     if($_POST['submit'])
        {
           $dbhost = 'localhost';
           $DBUSER = 'dbuser';
           $DBPASSWD = 'dbpass';
           $DATABASE = 'db';
           $backupPath = '/home/*****/public_html/admin/sql';


           $filename = "backup-" . date("d-m-Y");
          $cmd = "mysqldump --complete-insert --create-options --add-locks --disable-keys --extended-insert --quick --quote-names -u $user --password=$DBPASSWD $DATABASE|gzip --fast -c >{$backupPath}/$filename.sql.gz";   

           exec($cmd);

           echo $cmd;


        }
```

This is the code i want to use for dumping database. But i never get any backup to specified directory, it always show the error which i have mentioned on my code. Ca anyone tell me whats the problem? Thank you.

**N.B**
Update this one `-u $user` with this `--user $DBUSER` $user but nothing happened.

Comment: opps! sry copy paste from my original code,forget to remove this one. sry for that

Comment: Well add them back to the code and look at its content ;)

Comment: maybe because you use $user instead of $DBUSER

Comment: update this one but no luck :(

Comment: Are PHP errors turned on?

Comment: no dear PHP error turn off

Comment: @AshisBiswas Then turn them on, honey. We are not able to help you if you are not 100% sure what the problem is.

Comment: Set error_reporting(E_ALL) but no error display except `PHP Notice:  Undefined index: submit in`.

Comment: @AshisBiswas That means the form is not submitted. See, that was easy.

Comment: No form successfully submitted. This notice is for first time access the page so $_POST['submit'] is nothing and one thing if form is not submitted 'echo $cmd;` will not display on the page. Echo cmd display as expected.

Comment: `exec($cmd,$1,$2);var_dump($1);var_dump($2);`

Comment: what is the function of the code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sol-

```
  $filename = $backupPath . '/DB_' . time(). '.gz';
  if (file_exists($filename)) 
  {
       unlink($filename);
  }

 $cmd = 'mysqldump --opt -h '.$dbhost.' -u ' . $DBUSER . ' -p\'' . $DBPASSWD. '\' ' . $DATABASE . ' | gzip > ' . $filename;

  exec($cmd);
  echo $cmd;
```

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: I bet you would have found that out faster if you looked at the output from exec.